# What is the meaning of reverse=[i]+reverse

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing code in python to reverse a string and stumble upon this code.

```
lst = [21,2,3,1,96,55,66,12,19]

reverse = []

for i in lst:
    print([i])
    reverse = [i] + reverse
```

Wants to know what is the meaning of reverse=[i]+reverse, what does it do ?

I'm trying to reverse a list without using any function or built in methods.
I was thinking of something simple which doesn't involve any functions.

Comment: This is a great opportunity to learn how to use a debugger, which would let your step through your code line-by-line, and inspect the value of all the variables as they change. It's a really powerful tool, which would make the behaviour of this code quite obvious.

Answer (score 2):

1. `[i]` is just a list literal containing one element, `i`.
2. `+ reverse` is called on that, to produce a new list that starts with `i`, and
   ends with all the elements from the `reverse` list.
3. Finally, `reverse` is re-assigned to point to this new list.

In effect, this is building up the reversed list one element at a time.

Comment: To view that in plain english.
reverse=[i]+reverse is adding number from i to an empty list in reverse order